# Jquery function with setInterval

Tags: jquery

I tried to create function to increase number in div every second

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$('.number').setInterval(increaseNumber(), 1);

function increaseNumber() {
    var num = $(this).html() + 1;
    $(this).html(num);
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/3/

What's wrong with my code and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like this

```
var num=1;
setInterval(function(){
num++;
$(".number").html(num);
},1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `()`, pass a function but not the returned result.

```
// and the unit is millisecond, if you mean 1 seconds, then it should be 1000
// and setInterval is method form window
window.setInterval(increaseNumber, 1000);
```

And `this` inside `increaseNumber` refers to the `window` object, which is also wrong.

To make your code work, you may check the below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    window.setInterval(increaseNumber, 1000);

    function increaseNumber() {
        var num = $('.number');
        num.html(+num.html() + 1);
    }
});
```

***[And the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/8/)***

Comment: @truslivii.lev Check the demo I posted.